# JScrollPane doesnt cover a whole JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I dont know if I missed something or that this is a bug.
I have created a panel that contains several JTextArea
But the scrollpane let me only scroll to line 22. But there are 70 lines
And when I resize the frame, the scrollpane resize also and I can see more lines than when I only use the scrollbar to scroll down.

Never mind the code inside

State 1: [Image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18290052/state1.png)

State 2: [Image](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18290052/state2.png)

THERE ARE 70 LINES!
but I cant scroll to them

Any suggestions?


I only have set a rowheaderView:

```
jScrollPane1.setRowHeaderView(codeTextArea2.getRowNumbers());
```

And the viewportView:

```
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(codeTextArea2);
```

codeTextArea2 is the custom class that extends JPanel and contains several JTextArea

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information for me to be able to answer, but I have a guess: You're not using the ***null layout*** anywhere are you? If so, get rid of it and use valid layouts that the JScrollPane can handle. Also this, `"Never mind the code inside"` does us a grave disservice. How can you say that when you don't know what is causing your problem?

Comment: Also, could you be setting the size or the preferredSize of the component held by the viewportView?

Comment: Thanks a lot, It was a combination of using the null layout and set the preferredSize

Comment: You're welcome, but next time, please don't "never mind the code inside". If you knew the cause for your problem, you probably wouldn't be posting a question here. Show the code to us. Don't force us to guess.

Answer (score 4):

+1 to HFOE comments

> Never mind the code inside

The reason we do mind the code inside:

This seems to work fine for me as I dont have your code I simulated what I though you have in its simplest form.

Simply `JPanel` class which holds a single `JTextArea` with 70 rows and 20 columns, each is given a number by simple `append(..)` on normal size and maximize number of rows dont seems to change

[image]

(this one was too big for a full unresized screen shot)

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyPanelTextAreas panelWithTextAreas = new MyPanelTextAreas();

        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(panelWithTextAreas);
        jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 400));//dont want it too big 

        frame.add(jsp);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanelTextAreas extends JPanel {

    JTextArea area = new JTextArea(70, 20);

    public MyPanelTextAreas() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(area);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 70; i++) {
            area.append((i == 1 ? "" : "\n") + i);
        }
        area.setCaretPosition(1);
    }
}
```